# How do I get rid of the GPS navigation and replace it with an icon?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, gps

I have the Samsung Galaxy s4 with echoe rom v51 (lollipop 5.0.1 ) installed and I would like to learn how do I get rid of the GPS navigation text notification and replace it with an icon (of course disabling the GPS is out of question)?

[image: screenshot]

The screenshot is from my phone it sets on Greek language.